# bootstrap datetimepicker does not work in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I need to use bootstrap datetimepicker in a bootstrap modal. I've successfully used it in a normal web page. The bootstrap calender won't open in the modal. Here is my dynamically generated `html` code.

```
'<div class="col-xs-12">'+
    '<div class="col-xs-4">'+
    '<div class="form-group">'+
'<label for="editStartTime">Start Time </label>'+
      '<div class="input-group date" id="editStartTime">'+
           '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+startTime+'"/>'+
    '<span class="input-group-addon">'+
  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>'+
   '</span>'+
 '</div>'+
 '</div>'+
'</div>'
```

This is the `jquery` part.

```
$(function () {
                $('#editStartTime').datetimepicker();
            });
```

what will be the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to instantiate the datepicker again after the dynamic html is added to the DOM. You could call it on the bootstrap modal shown event:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#editStartTime').datetimepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add z-index above 1051 in class datepicker

add something like this in page or css

```
<style>
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: Try .datepicker instead of .datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

'StartTime'  isn't found as as ID in your sample.

Perhaps you need to use '#editStartTme'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're targeting the correct element. You specify `$("#StartTime")...` which would look for an element in your HTML with an ID (#) of `id="StartTime"`. Notice in your provided HTML that doesn't exist:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+startTime+'"/>'+
```

Either add an id `id="startTime"` or class `class="form-control startTime` and target it properly in your jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $('#startTime').datetimepicker(); // # for ID
  // or
  $('.startTime').datetimepicker(); // . for class
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the event `show.bs.modal` which occurs when the modal is about to be shown, so you can get the input instance when it's already created in the document to configure the `datetimepicker`.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','.modal', function () {
  $('#editStartTime').datetimepicker();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Keeps this js before end of script. This works for me.

```
// Since confModal is essentially a nested modal it's enforceFocus method
// must be no-op'd or the following error results 
// "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
// But then when the nested modal is hidden we reset modal.enforceFocus
var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

$confModal.on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
});
```