# Bootstrap 3 datepicker in bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to get the Bootstrap 3 date picker to display in a bootstrap modal. I followed the installation instructions and examples but it is not appearing in my modal or anywhere else on the website.

I have installed jquery-3.2.1.min.js, I have a CDN pointing to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/locale/af.js and I also have the bootstrap-datetimepicker.css installed.

Can anyone help me figure this out please!

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary-outline dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
  data-toggle="modal" aria-haspopup="true" data-target="#traffic">
  TRAFFIC FOR THIS WEEK
</button>

<!-- Start Modal / Edit Schedule -->
<div id="traffic" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="calendarfilters">
          <div style="overflow:hidden;">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                  inline: true,
                  sideBySide: true
                });
              });
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal / Edit Schedule -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap datetimepicker does not work in a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520327/bootstrap-datetimepicker-does-not-work-in-a-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: @VincenzoC Thank you for the link. But I ended up finding this awesome datepicker at http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/ and it worked like a charm.